# How do I uninstall Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I now have two versions of Xcode installed:

- Xcode 4 - installed in /Developer (bought from Mac App Store)
- Xcode 3 - installed in /Developer-old (I believe it was installed from the second disc supplied with my MCB)

Since I don't use either of those at the moment, how can I completely remove both?
Would removing both folder just do the job?
What about associated Library stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode comes with an uninstaller. Just run

```
sudo <Xcode directory>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: Thanks. There were a few leftovers (sym-links) after that. A little bit more left after uninstalling /Developer-old but since the uninstaller completed its job I removed those manually.

Comment: The readme for the perl script mentions that it leaves a few directories and how to delete them. You did the right thing to clean them up.