# Problems when trying to delete/uninstall Xcode

Tags: mac, xcode, macos

I'm trying to uninstall Xcode. I dragged the application to the trash and tried to delete but it hung for a while and then said it couldn't be deleted because some of its files were in use. However, now the icon looks like this:

[image]

I searched and found another answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16420/how-do-i-uninstall-xcode) that says to run:

```
sudo <Xcode directory>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

I just want to confirm that this won't cause any issues with my existing Xcode projects. I'm really just trying to uninstall Xcode to free up space on my hard drive in order to download the newest version of Xcode (I don't have the free space to simply download the new version/update).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you rebooted and then tried to empty the trash?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to confirm that this won't cause any issues with my existing Xcode projects.

It won't.

As long as you don't delete any project files and data you'll be fine. Also make sure to keep you projects backed on.

Comment: Great, thanks. Sorry for a newbie follow-up, but do I copy and paste that command as-is, or do I need to replace "Xcode directory" with something else? I just tried it and got the error `-bash: Xcode: No such file or directory`

Comment: The sudo command is from a very old version of Xcode - the uninstall-devtools is not there anymore

Comment: @Mark I see.. so if this isn't the command I need to uninstall Xcode is there a different method where I can get around the error?